# My SQL query for join multiple tables via mm

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im looking for a SQL statement for the structue below. I want select all uid's and texts of the tables, which got a relation to the table *declined*:

- partsofspeech
- verbs_tempus
- words_case
- words_language
- words_relation

Each table has the fields *uid* and *text*.
Each table got a mm table to save any relation. The *local* value belongs to the *uid* of related table itself. Foreign represents the *uid* of *decline*.

I want do this with 1 SQL query. I think it should be possible with joins but im new with these. Here is a 'lil graphic: [image]

Here is my query:

```
SELECT partsofspeech.uid, partsofspeech.text from declined
LEFT JOIN partsofspeech_mm
ON partsofspeech_mm.foreign = declined.uid
LEFT JOIN partsofspeech
ON partsofspeech_mm.local = partsofspeech.uid
```

fiddle:

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0af271/2)

Does any1 has a clue to handle this recursive probably?

Comment: Since you are new and didn't post your version of the query and expecting help on writing one for you, at least [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20724943/edit) you question and provide **relevant sample data and desired output** in textual form or better yet create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). Otherwise your question most likely will be closed.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. But maybe this might do the trick. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0af271/22

Comment: BTW is it not possible to do the data manipulation outside MYSQL? Perhaps with PHP?

Comment: i will manipulate the My SQL results later with PHP. I don't want pass to many queries for one result with PHP if i can avoid it with database intern stuff. After i read @Tintran example with `INNER JOIN`. this might the behaviour which i want to force. ty for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the first table `partsofspeech` done for you

```
SELECT T1.uid,T1.text,T2.local,T2.foreign,T3.uid,T3.text
  FROM partsofspeech T1
  INNER JOIN partsofspeech_nm T2 ON (T1.uid = T2.local)
  INNER JOIN declined T3 ON (T2.foreign = T3.uid)
```

you can do the rest for the other tables and `UNION` them together.

Comment: Ty for your answer.

i got confused with the post system here and created a new post accidentally. (hope i deleted it correctly) :/

[sql fiddle][1]
  [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0af271/2

im using left joins to do it atm.

is there any way to get the following parts short in a recursive way?

Comment: A question to *INNER JOIN*. I'm not very familar with the different types:
Does it provide me to get empty results?

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `UNION`. I did not know it before.

Comment: according to your fiddle, you're using LEFT JOIN it'll always give you values from declined table and nulls for where there's no match in other tables. If you use INNER JOIN it'll only give you rows if there are matching values in all 3 tables. hope i explained that correctly